# how to separate unique names which is in excel sheet using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

```
Engineer    DC          Competency  Date    Effort
Engineer-1  Center-1    Electronics 17-Aug-15   6
Engineer-2  Center-1    Software    13-Aug-15   5
Engineer-3  Center-1    Mechanical  17-Aug-15   6
Engineer-4  Center-1    Testing     17-Aug-15   7
Engineer-5  Center-1    Firmware    17-Aug-15   5
Engineer-4  Center-2    Testing     18-Aug-15   6
Engineer-5  Center-2    Firmware    13-Aug-15   7
Engineer-2  Center-3    Software    18-Aug-15   7
Engineer-3  Center-3    Mechanical  19-Aug-15   6
Engineer-4  Center-3    Testing     19-Aug-15   5
Engineer-2  Center-4    Software    13-Aug-15   4
Engineer-3  Center-4    Mechanical  20-Aug-15   7
Engineer-4  Center-4    Testing     20-Aug-15   6
Engineer-1  Center-5    Electronics 20-Aug-15   5
```

Here is the data which is in the excel sheet how to separate the unique engineer names and there effort of each engineer and total effort of each engineer

```
           expected output like this-------
                      total effort(effort of each engineer in current week)
       Engineer-1        11
       Engineer-2        16
       Engineer-3        18
       Engineer-4        18
       Engineer-5        12
```

i should write using python code using xlrd, here where ever Engineer-1 are there that should be separate where ever Engineer 2 are that should be separate like this for every engineer and their effort we get as total hours spent in the 34th week

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel pivot table like this.
[Link](https://www.google.com.tw/search?espv=2&biw=757&bih=794&tbm=isch&q=excel%20pivot%20table%20tutorial&revid=247638638&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q1QIoAGoVChMIia-y5pa5xwIVBaumCh3VFQi2)